# JQuery: Can't open dialog box

Tags: jquery, user-interface, dialog

I am having trouble opening the dialog box div. When I try to open the dialog like this, nothing happens:

```
$(this).closest('div.editable').find('.update-dialog').dialog("open");
```

And when I try to access the dialog div element to see if I'm actually getting anything,

```
alert($(this).closest('div.editable').find('.update-dialog').prop("class"));
```

Alert returns "undefined". But how can this be? The div.update-dialog is a sibling of the button element (this), so calling "find" on the result returned by "closest" should get me div.update-dialog.

Here is the full code. The areas of interest are marked by comments:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>sourcecode test</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- DIALOG DIV - note the hierarchy/tree of the html elements -->
<div class ="editable" id="div_John E. Coons[instructor_status]"contenteditable="1">

    <span class="text-error">Error: More than one user with same fname and lname</span>
    <br/>Users:
    <br/>
    <span class="multiple-users">&nbsp Instructor ID: 23, Common Name: John E. Coons</span>
    <br/>
    <span class="multiple-users">&nbsp Instructor ID: 17447, Common Name: John E Coons</span>
    <br/>
    <div class="update-dialog" title="Update Common Name">Which instructor do you want to update?
        <p><input type="radio" id="instructor_23" name="instructor" value="23"/>
            <label for="instructor_23">Instructor ID: 23, Common Name: John E. Coons</label>
        </p>

        <p>
            <input type="radio" id="instructor_17447" name="instructor" value="17447"/>
            <label for="instructor_17447">Instructor ID: 17447, Common Name: John E Coons</label>
        </p>Which common name do you want to assign the instructor?

        <p>
            <input type="radio" id="commonName_23" name="common_name" value="John E. Coons"/>
            <label for="commonName_23">John E. Coons</label>
        </p>

        <p>
            <input type="radio" id="commonName_17447" name="common_name" value="John E Coons"/>
            <label for="commonName_17447">John E Coons </label>
        </p>

    </div>

    <button class="update-button" type="button">Update Common Name of an Instructor</button>
</div>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
      // creates dialog in div
      $("div.update-dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            dialogClass: 'dialogStyle',
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Update": function() {
                //$.load('update_common_name.php', 
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
       });

     // FIX THIS: DIALOG DOES NOT OPEN ON CLICK
     $('div.editable').on('click', 'button.update-button', function () {
        $(this).closest('div.editable').find('.update-dialog').dialog("open");

        // alert test returns "undefined"
        alert($(this).closest('div.editable').find('.update-dialog').prop("class"));

     }); 




     $('input:radio').change(function () {        

        if ($(this).attr('name') === 'instructor') {
            instructor_id = $(this).val();
        }
        if ($(this).attr('name') === 'common_name') {
            common_name = $(this).val();
        }
        alert(instructor_id + common_name);
     }); 


});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is it on JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5fKYn/  . Does the DOM change after the dialog has been associated with the div?

Comment: Does the DOM change after the dialog has been associated with the div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that you will have more than one ".editable" on the page you should use a plugin style approach to wiring up the beahaviour you are trying to achieve:

```
$(function() {

    jQuery(".editable").each(function()
    {
        var $this = jQuery(this);
        // Select the button within the scope of the current ".editable"
        var $btnUpdate = jQuery(".update-button", $this);

        // Create the dialog within the scope of the current ".editable"
        var $dialogElm = $("div.update-dialog", $this).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        dialogClass: 'dialogStyle',
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Update": function() {
            //$.load('update_common_name.php', 
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
        });

        // Attach button behaviour with in the scope of the current ".editable"
        $btnUpdate.on('click', function () {
            $dialogElm.dialog("open");
        }); 

        $('input:radio', $this).change(function () {        
            if ($(this).attr('name') === 'instructor') {
                instructor_id = $(this).val();
            }
            if ($(this).attr('name') === 'common_name') {
                common_name = $(this).val();
            }
            alert(instructor_id + common_name);
        }); 

    });
});
```

Comment: Noob question: how does this style help?

Comment: It allows you to have multiple instances of any given piece of functionality without the use of ID's and prevents from the need to  re-execute jQuery() element look-ups each time you interact with it after the initial .onReady()

Answer (score 1):

The dialog box is being moved out of its position in the DOM to be a root element of the `body` tag. This is a fairly common way to treat dialogs.

changing your code to

```
$('div.editable').on('click', 'button.update-button', function () {
    $('.update-dialog').dialog('open');
    $('.update-dialog').prop('class');
});
```

will work but i would recommend using id identifiers rather than class since all dialogs will be at the same DOM level.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5fKYn/5/)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. Is there any documentation explaining this dialog box movement?

Comment: I'm not sure, you can easily see the change by looking at the DOM with developer tools though.